# How do you say "closure"?

Tags: meaning

How do Germans say "closure," as in emotional closure. For example, "We need to talk about when we broke up so that I can feel closure about our relationship."

Comment: what did your research show? have you consulted a dictionary? share your current status. Where are you confused?

Answer (score 6):

The problem here is that English and German deal with this concept in different ways.
In English, the concept can be summed up with one noun:

- closure

In German, we express this in a number of verb constructions, depending on the individual situation:

- über etwas hinweg kommen (to get over sth.)
- etwas abschließen (to achieve closure, close the book,...)
- etwas verarbeiten (to deal with sth. [heavy psychological implication])
- etwas aufarbeiten (to deal with sth. [even heavier psychological implication - almost certainly in a therapy context])

In the last decades, people talk much more about this and naturally, in the course of globalisation, people find themselves stumped when they want to switch between the very handy English noun and the comparatively cumbersome German.
So far, I don't see a "real" noun equivalent in German.

Comment: I think I'd say “mit etwas abschließen”, although I am not sure that I could justify it.

Comment: Hmm, to me, the addition of "mit" turns the phrase into "to turn one's back on sth.", i.e. it hasn't the overtones of "healing" the English *closure* seems to carry.

Answer (score 3):

Even though of course every German verb can be substantivized, I'd rather use a verb phrase such as "... damit ich mit unserer Beziehung abschließen kann".

Answer (score 1):

Wie Uwe schon geschrieben hat, ist eine Substantivierung in solchen Fällen unpassend.

Einer meiner Kollegen wies mich darauf hin, dass diese Ausdrucksart sogar kontraproduktiv sein kann. Sein Wortlaut: "Das ist Juristensprech, ehrliche Leute verwenden Verben."

*Closure* erinnert mich eher an [Verwaltungstätigkeiten](http://dict.leo.org/?lp=ende&search=closure). *Abwicklung* wäre ein Beispiel für eine ganz grausame Übersetzung in dieser Situation, auch wenn es schön klingen würde. Wikipedia klicken brachte mich zu [Closure (psychology)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28psychology%29), führt dann aber nicht zum Ziel bzw. irgendwo zu weit.

Ich vermute es geht um die Bewältigung von Trennungsschmerz oder die Verarbeitung einer beendeten Beziehung? Sofern es bei einer einfachen Formulierung bleiben soll, ist **Uwes Vorschlag** wohl die **beste Lösung**.

Comment: Grundsätzlich tolle Antwort - das Zitat Deines Kollegen ist klasse! Der dritte Absatz (zu *closure*) passt allerdings nicht so gut dazu. Speziell der "vorrangige" Buchhalterbezug verwirrt mich ein wenig - das höre ich zum ersten Mal.

Comment: Vielleicht ist habe ich mich auch schlecht ausgedrückt. Unter den Ergebnissen von [LEO](http://dict.leo.org/?lp=ende&search=closure) kamen mir Zusammenhänge im Rahmen von Betriebsstilllegung und abschließen eines Falls am bekanntesten vor.

Comment: Ah, ok - das Problem bei LEO ist, dass viele Einträge situationsbezogen entstehen und nicht nach Häufigkeit gewichtet werden. Da es für "Abwicklung" eine Handvoll Synonyme gibt, ist diese Bedeutung bei LEO extrem überrepräsentiert. Die psychologische *closure* ist tatsächlich, was hier gemeint ist - mittlerweile ein ziemlich gängiger Begriff.